Не могу понять почему не работает алгоритм
Есть задание - составить алгоритм, ищущий все простые числа от 1 до x.
Моё решение.
let x = 10;
let y = 2;
for (x; x > 1; --x) {
  for (y; y < x; ++y) {
        if (x % y === 0) break;
        if (y === x-1) {console.log(y)}
  }
}

Не могу понять в чём ошибка.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Натуральные числа не нужно искать, цикл их перечисляет. Вероятно, вам нужны простые числа?

y нужно инициализировать в начале цикла каждый раз. А у вас один раз y инициализируется до всех циклов и поэтому второй и последующие циклы по y уже не будут отрабатывать, потому что y уже вышло за x ещё в первую отработку цикла по y и больше никогда обратно не вернётся. Напишите нормальные циклы, с нормальной инициализацией и эта ошибка уйдёт хотя бы.

Прописал x = 10 и y = 2 в начале циклов, всё равно выдаёт 6, 4, 2 в консоли, не понимаю почему.

Наверное, печатать то нужно x, а не y? Ну и 1 и 2 простые числа по определению, "вычислить" вы их не сможете, по идее.

Спасибо огромное.

Переделанный код:
for (let x = 10; x > 1; --x) {
  let prime = true;
  for (let y = 2; y < x; ++y) {
        if (x % y === 0) {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
  }
  if (prime) {
      console.log(x)
  }
}

Вывод:
7
5
3
2

Суть переделок:

Инициализация переменной y каждый раз внутри цикла по x, а не один раз как у вас
Печатаем на выходе x, а не y
Чтобы можно было вывести также и числа 1 и 2 пришлось переделать логику проверки - добавил булевый флаг для этого, без этой переделки 1 и 2 не напечатается


Натуральное число 1 не является ни простым, ни составным.

@Oopss Ай! ))  Исправлю, спасибо!
